# Div will not pick up correct image size from php generated content

Tags: php, html, overflow

I have a user file interface i'm trying to modify but my div isn't picking up the php generated content and resizing.

You can see it at: http://test3.hejmej.com (at least until the problem is resolved)

Here is the coding:

---

```
<?php 
include 'auth.php';
include 'header.php';
?>
<div class="tabs">
<div class="tab files active"><a href="index.php"><img src="img/files.png" alt=""     class="icon">My Files</a></div>
<div class="tab info"><a href="details.php"><img src="img/info-inactive.png" alt="" class="icon"> Account Information</a></div>
<div class="tab close"><a href="logout.php"></a></div>
</div>
<div class="section">
<?php $user->welcome(); ?>
</div>
<ul class="section" style="border-style:solid; border-width:10px; border-color:red;">
<?php $user->get_files();
if ( count( $user->files ) )
    foreach( $user->files as $file )
    echo '<li style="width:115px; height:115x;"><a href="file.php?name='.urlencode($file).'"><img src="file.php?name='.urlencode($file).'" height="100" width="100" /></a></li>';
else
    echo 'There are no files for you at the moment.';
?>
</ul>
<?php $universal = new User( 'universal' );
    if( $universal->exists() ) {
    $universal->get_files();
if ( count( $universal->files ) ) {
    echo '<ul class="section">Files that are avaible for all users:';
            foreach( $universal->files as $file )
echo '<li><a href="file.php?universal=true&name='.urlencode($file).'">'.$file.'</a>     <small>'.size($universal->path.$file).'</small></li>';
echo '</ul>';
}
} ?>

<?php include 'footer.php'; ?>
```

Comment: in the link you are providing I see a form. Where the tabs supposed to go in relation to the form .section?

Comment: sorry I forgot I have it user protected.

Comment: Log in with    ice0mike   test090

username:password